# Cannot call function that expects list of double

Tags: python, swig

I'm testing out a python library that is a SWIG wrapper.

One of the functions in this library is:

```
def point_inside(self, *args) -> "bool":
    return _vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, *args)
```

As far as I can tell, this function should take either a list of double, or three doubles.

When I call it with three numbers, it works:

```
>>> tri.point_inside(100,100,100)  
True
```

When I call it with a list of numbers, it fails:

```
>>> tri.point_inside([100,100,100])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Maptek\Vulcan 10.1\bin\exe\lib\site-packages\vulcan.py", line 1551, in point_inside
    return _vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, *args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    TRI_triangulation_t::point_inside(double_list)
    TRI_triangulation_t::point_inside(double,double,double)
```

Is there some syntax I'm missing to invoke the second overload correctly?

---

Not sure whether this is useful, but when I call a different function that *returns* list of double I get the obvious result.

```
def get_elevations(self, x: 'double', y: 'double') -> "double_list":
    return _vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_get_elevations(self, x, y)

>>> tri.get_elevations(100,100)
[88.0, 88.0, 112.0, 112.0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant here, but precisely speaking, your arguments are integers, not doubles. Maybe try with `100.0` instead of `100`?

Comment: @Blckknght you're right, but I should have specified that adding a decimal portion makes no difference, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*args` means accept a sequence of arguments and then wrap them into one variable `args` when using in function definition. And means unwrap all arguments when using in passing parameters.

In your first example, `args=(100, 100, 100)`, so calling `_vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, *args)` equals to `_vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, 100, 100, 100)`.

In your second example, if I understand you well, you want to make it work with just one argument which is a list.

In this case, you need to manually decide the type of your arguments:

```
def point_inside(self, double_or_list, *args) -> "bool":
    if isinstance(double_or_list, list):
        return _vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, *double_or_list)
    else:
        return _vulcanpy.TRI_triangulation_t_point_inside(self, double_or_list, *args)
```

## updated

Or you can unwrap list first `tri.point_inside(*[100,100,100])`

Comment: I can't change the functions defined in the library.

Comment: OK, in this case, you can only pass several arguments instead of only one list. Or you can unwrap list first `tri.point_inside(*[100,100,100])`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about unwrapping the list. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it?